# Analysis of Conditions with no results and high offset number - PostgreSQL JSONB

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, json, offset-fetch

I am asked to record down the analysis on PostgreSQL JSONB query having Conditions with high offset number and query that provide no results considering the below.

```
select
    *
from
    sub_test df,
    jsonb_array_elements(json_data) jba
where
    (jba->>'name')::text = 'SubYear'
    and (jba->>'value')::numeric > '2050';
```

1. SubYear > 2200 (has no results)
   Explanations about the query plan, are full scans of tables necessary with JSON?
2. SubYear > 1970 (has a lot of results) and offset 30k
   Explanations about the query plan, are full scans of tables necessary with JSON?

Note that there are about 35k+ records in the table "sub_test" with 500+ keys in the JSONB column "json_data"

Could you help me to answer them ?

Comment: Neither condition can make use of the index as the column used is the result of the cross join (that unnests the array elements). You should really consider normalizing your data model

Comment: Thanks, If the above query is rewritten as below, what would be the response for the 2 questions mentioned in the main ? select
    a.*
from
    (
    select
        st_id, jsonb_array_elements(json_data)jba
    from
        sub_test df )a
where
    cast(a.jba->>'name' as text) = 'SubYear'
    and cast(a.jba->>'value' as numeric) > '2050';

Comment: That's exactly the same query

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is because my JSONB is array of objects. If you don't mind, could you consider the below query  -   select
 *
from
 sub_test df
where
 cast(json_data->>'name' as text) = 'SubYear'
 and cast(json_data->>'value' as numeric) > '2050';

Comment: Well, `json_data->>'name'` won't work if `json_data` contains an array at the top level (and the result of the `->>` operator is already a `text` value, no need to cast it to `text`)

Comment: I understand that. Basically I need explanation with respect to " 1 ) when query the jsonb (no array) with highest offset number and 2) when query jsonb (no array) that results no data", how the query plan works and are full scans of tables necessary ? Your inputs would really help me a lot on it. Kindly help to clarify me.

Comment: Could you help me to clarify my above stated ?

Comment: As I said: there is no way you can create an index to support a range query if the values are inside a JSON array. You should seriously consider normalizing your data model